# How to split a dataframe and plot some columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 990 rows and 7 columns, I want to make a XvsY linear graph, broking the line at every 22 rows.

I think that dividing the dataframe and then plotting it will be good way, but I don't get good results.

```py
max_rows = 22
dataframes = []
while len(Co1new) > max_rows:
    top = Co1new[:max_rows]
    dataframes.append(top)
    Co1new = Co1new[max_rows:]
else:
    dataframes.append(Co1new)

for grafico in dataframes:
     AC = plt.plot(grafico)
     AC = plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
     AC = plt.ylabel("Temperature (K)")
plt.show()
```

The code functions but it is not plotting the right columns.

Here some reduced data and in this case it should be divided at every four rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1':[2.17073,2.14109,2.16052,2.81882,2.29713,2.26273,2.26479,2.7643,2.5444,2.5027,2.52532,2.6778],
'col2':[10,100,1000,10000,10,100,1000,10000,10,100,1000,10000],
'col3':[2.17169E-4,2.15889E-4,2.10526E-4,1.53785E-4,2.09867E-4,2.07583E-4,2.01699E-4,1.56658E-4,1.94864E-4,1.92924E-4,1.87634E-4,1.58252E-4]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of is to add a new column with labels for every 22 records. See below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks')

"""
Assuming the index is numeric and is from [0-990)
this will return an integer for every 22 records
"""
Co1new['subset'] = 'S' + np.floor_divide(Co1new.index, 22).astype(str)

Out:

    col1    col2    col3    subset
0   2.17073 10      0.000217    S0
1   2.14109 100     0.000216    S0
2   2.16052 1000    0.000211    S0
3   2.81882 10000   0.000154    S0
4   2.29713 10      0.000210    S1
5   2.26273 100     0.000208    S1
6   2.26479 1000    0.000202    S1
7   2.76434 10000   0.000157    S1
8   2.54445 10      0.000195    S2
9   2.50270 100     0.000193    S2
10  2.52532 1000    0.000188    S2
11  2.67780 10000   0.000158    S2
```

You can then use `seaborn.pairplot` to plot your data pairwise and use `Co1new['subset']` as legend.

```
seaborn.pairplot(Co1new, hue='subset')
```

[image]

Or if you absolutely need line charts, you can make line charts of your data, each pair at a time separately, here is col1 vs. col3

```
seaborn.lineplot('col1', 'col3', hue='subset', data=Co1new)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help @SIA, but then I will need to fit an equation in  some columns separately.

Comment: Could you post a sample dataset and what you expect to see in the graph?

Comment: The sample dataset is too big and I don't know how to add.

Comment: just select a small subset that has the characteristics of your complete dataset, you can type it in here as a dataframe like `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[...], 'col2':[...],  'col3':[...],  'col4':[...],  'col5':[...],  'col6':[...],  'col7':[...]})` where `[...]` are list objects of values in your dataset for each column.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2.17073,2.14109,2.16052,2.81882,2.29713,2.26273,2.26479,2.76434,2.54445,2.5027,2.52532,2.6778], 'col2':[10,100,1000,10000,10,100,1000,10000,10,100,1000,10000], 'col3':[2.17169E-4,2.15889E-4,2.10526E-4,1.53785E-4,2.09867E-4,2.07583E-4,2.01699E-4,1.56658E-4,1.94864E-4,1.92924E-4,1.87634E-4,1.58252E-4], 'col4':[...], 'col5':[...], 'col6':[...], 'col7':[...]})...

Comment: You can edit your original post and copy the data there

Comment: hopefully `seaborn.pairplot` gets you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using @SIA ' s answer

```
df['groups'] = np.floor_divide(df.index, 3).astype(str)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x="col1", y="col2", color='groups')
fig.show()
```

[image: example dataframe]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help @aunsid, but I get the next error: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot... And shows two graphs with a few data... I want only one graph for all of the data...

Comment: 1. that error is because of having some values as type object in your df. you need to do astype(float) 2. for plotting if its a scatter matrix use mine or SIA's suggested method.

Comment: Sorry, but all the data is numeric. I need a linear plot of two columns from the entire data, but separately... because it's like time; I have data every 24 hours and this is X in XvsY graph. If I plot everything I will see so many lines and not a clear pattern.

Comment: I need a linear plot of two columns from the entire data, but separately lines in one graph. Maybe, I explained wrong... If I plot the entire data, I will see a line crossing from 24 to 0...

Comment: well, out of the 7 you need to plot 2 columns, right? and for every 22 rows? So you will have 990/22 linear plots with some x and y.

Comment: I have 7 columns and from these columns I want a XvsY plot of two columns from these 7.